# Identify breaker panel

Tags: electrical-panel

We are buying a 40 year old house with this breaker panel on the inside, but **there is no door or any markings I can see identifying the brand of the panel**. The main 200amp breaker seems fairly unique to me, so hoping that can help narrow it down.

[image]

Comment: IF the type MP-T breaker actually belongs there, that would apparently make it a Murray panel. But the sparkies will probably be able to eyeball the other breakers  and tell better. It certainly looks "alien" or at least details don't fit with all the other breakers.

Comment: Well, I did find a picture of a  200A Murray breaker that has that funny hump, so you might be in luck that way...

Comment: That main breaker is almost definitely related to the [Murray MD2200A](https://breakeroutlet.com/circuit-breakers/siemens/md-a-md2200a-murray-2-pole-200a-plug-on-main-circuit-breaker/), though your handle seems to go the opposite direction from the handle in the pictures here.

Comment: Another thing pointing to Murray: https://www.ebay.com/itm/222981539902 shows a vintage Murray double breaker which has the same pointed handles that you have. New replacement breakers all seem to have the typical "straight" handles.

Comment: That looks like an older Murray I remember when I was an apprentice Murray was MP, CH was brown, QO was square D with the flag , Zinsco were double long, stab lock had a red stripe back then there was no legal cross breaker type That Siemens/GE , sq D hom & Murray can use Eaton breakers that are certified for those panels. We had to keep them all separate (still do with old) but some new are cross certified or listed now. @manassehkatz, I also remember the tapered handles on the old ones.

Comment: Photo of the panel labeling, please? It may be inside the screw-on deadfront.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The OP stated that the door is missing and there are no markings.

Comment: I find it interesting that several of the breakers are off and/or tripped. The whole thing would be a red flag to me. If I made an offer, it would be contingent on a full inspection of at least the panel.

Comment: @DoxyLover Of course, it could be as simple as: House sitting empty so turned off all non-essential circuits instead of bothering to turn off/unplug vampire loads, etc.

Comment: I don't know the local regulations, and I don't know the benefit of identifying the panel, but I think the more important question is whether the panel still satisfies current regulations. At least here in Germany you are not allowed to do such installations, and any professional electrician would be required to replace any equipment (e.g. fault current switch) that does not adhere to current standards. I also live in an older house and turning on the PC frequently triggers the 16A (230V) circuit  breaker.

Comment: @U.Windl FYI: in the US, all existing equipment is considered legal so long as it met code on the date it was installed. There is no requirement (that I'm aware of) anywhere in the country requiring an update to current code prior to a house sale. If there were, it would kill off the sales of a lot of older houses (like mine) that still have knob & tube wiring, or other no longer legal wiring. Also, in the US, the homeowner is allowed to do electrical work on his own residence.

Comment: Since there have been comments asking for pictures of the labeling on the door, I edited the post to emphasize that _there is no door_ for the OP to take pics of.

Comment: @U.Windl I am pretty sure you are mistaken - the panel in my house is 25 years old now.  About 5 years ago an electrician added a new outside socket; he did not insist on replacing the panel, despite the fact I am _sure_ it would not be legal to install now.  (BW to be specific.)

Comment: @DoxyLover Deadfront and door are not the same thing.  NEMA 1 panels often don't even have doors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The older breakers with their beveled handles, and in particular the rounded-over main breaker case, is the distinctive design language of Murray panels.

It doesn't really work to look at 1 breaker in a panel and guess what panel it is, because people put the wrong breakers in panels all the time (and that is dangerous).

However, when ALL the older breakers speak one particular design language, it's a sure bet that's the panel type.

Murray is a perfectly common and current panel type, and it takes Siemens MP breakers (which Siemens has oddly renamed to QP for no good reason). Siemens MP/QP breakers are fine.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a Murray panel I say that because of the Murray breaker MP-T I Willy pull one of the others after turning off and verify. Some old ones had the tapered handle.

Comment: The OP could remove the cover and there's probably a label inside +

Comment: The OP does not own the house yet and may not have permission to get that detailed in the pre-purchase inspection.